# Unresolved references from androidx.compose.animation and androidx.compose.animation.core

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Can anyone help me to find the replacement of below from compose animation and core.

- androidx.compose.animation.DpPropKey
- androidx.compose.animation.core.transitionDefinition
- androidx.compose.animation.core.state
- androidx.compose.animation.core.TransitionState

All are working fine with

```
compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha05'
```

but not working with

```
composeVersion = '1.0.0-beta06'
```

Unfortunately could not find in documentation https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole set of animations [were changed](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1516022) with a new set without a mapping 1:1.

Now you can use `updateTransition` or r`ememberInfiniteTransition`.
More details [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#updateTransition).